# How do I return an array from a JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I am trying to export an array from a JavaScript function, but there seems to be an issue. The code for the function is the following:

```
function fetchThemesList() {
let themes = new Array()
let options = {(...)}
request(options, function(error, response, body) {
    let i = 0;
    JSON.parse(body).forEach(element => {
        themes.push(element.name)
        //console.log(themes)   debug
    });
    return themes;
})}
fetchThemesList();
```

What I want to do is return the value of the `themes` variable, but regardless of what I do, it just won't work. When using `console.log` in the function itself I'll either get `undefined` or an empty array (`[]`). But when I try to log inside of the function, removing the comment mark, I will see the results being added to the array:

```
$ node themes.js
undefined
[ 'result-zero' ]
[ 'result-zero', 'result-one' ]
```

It seems like the function is being executed async, and the blank array is being output first, but I've tried using Promises with the same code and got the same results.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have stated in the post: I tried Promises and achieved no success. This isn't a duplicate

Comment: All the information you need is available in the link above your question.